# Join sql table with two other tables

Tags: mysql, join, right-join

```
SELECT * FROM rss as r right outer join wallhasrss wr on r.idRss=wr.Rss_idRss 
right outer join userhasrss ur on ur.Rss_idRss=r.idRss where ur.User_idUser=6 and wr.wall_idwall=12;
```

I would like to join an sql table with two tables.

I want to join rss with wallhasrss and with userhasrss. For example:

```
rss
idRss
1
2

wallhasrss
Rss_idRss
1

userhasrss
Rss_idRss
2
```

If the tables are like listed above I want the output to be

```
1
2
```

1 because of the join with wallhasrss and 2 because of the join with userhasrss. Is this possible are do I need the union operator. I tried with the right join but it doesnt work.

Comment: What happens when you try your query?

Comment: Your query includes columns that you don't show in your sample tables.

Comment: it returns nothing, In the sample tables I just showed the columns that are used in joins.

Comment: But you have a `WHERE` clause that filters based on those other columns. That may be the reason you get no results. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

USE **`LEFT JOIN`**

```
SELECT distinct idRss
FROM rss R
LEFT JOIN wallhasrss W ON R.idRss=W.Rss_idRss
LEFT JOIN userhasrss U ON R.idRss=U.Rss_idRss
```

**[STUDY JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**